# Variable not found error in React Native code with lodash transform

Tags: javascript, react-native, lodash

I imported lodash in my react native code.

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

I'm getting variable 'r' not found on below code, the line marked with a comment.

```
makeMarkedDates(){

             testDates={
                "2017-10-01": 1,
                "2017-10-04": 1,
                "2017-10-08": 1,
            };




            _.transform(testDates, (r, value, key) =>{
/*Getting error here=>*/                (r[key] || (r[key] = [])).push({ startingDay: true, color: '#FF0000', textColor: '#FFFFFF' }, { endingDay: true, color: '#FF0000', textColor: '#FFFFFF' })
            }, {}); 

        console.log(r);

        }
```

Comment: You're trying to log r outside of the function where it's defined... and why don't you use Array reduce anyway?

Comment: I dont use lodash, but first off, your console.log(r) will never work. Your declaring r as a parameter variable within the transform function. The outside scope has no idea what r is.

Comment: Thanks @DanielZuzevich and Dominic. That was the issue.